# Question regarding proof of: For any x and any base b, $x = log_{b}(b^{x}$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, exponentiation

I am reading 'A beginners guide to discrete mathematics'. And i stumbled on this proof they have:

**Theorem**. For any x and any base b, $x = log_{b}(b^{x})$

**Proof**. By definition, $u = b\text{ }log_{b}(u)$. Putting $ u = b^{x}$ we have $bx = b(log_{b}(b^{x}))$. So comparing the exponents, $x = log_{b}(b^{x})$

**How the book writes it:**[image: Proof from book]

Why does $u = b\text{ }log_{b}(u)$ make any sense? e.g. $16 = 2*log_{2}(16)$,
so what they are saying is that $16 = 8$ ? or is there something i am misunderstanding by the way they write "By definition" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appear to be a typo.  Try $u = b^{\log_b u}$, which is true (and differs mostly in white space).  The same typographical error comes when setting $u =b^x$, but "$bx$" appears on the left-hand side of the substituted equation.

Comment: Yeah okay. It's just the second typo i find in their math in the first 7 pages. Going to be a rough ride if you can't trust them.

Comment: @DenLilleMand : These sorts of typos seem to be *everywhere* in e-Book versions of textbooks.  I'm aware of at least one Calculus e-textbook that had dropped *every* superscript to the baseline.  That was ... comically bad.

Comment: But now that i read it again, i guess the typo was slightly obvious, i am just not used to math, which is why i am reading a beginners book.

Comment: Yeah but i have a physical copy, and the same error is there.